# Can I get by without adding Vetur to my Vue.js 3 Apps?

Tags: vue.js, vetur

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop Vue.js 3 apps. In my early learning on vuemastery.com it was instructed to use Vetur, but I'm finding that Vetur is too much of a hassle to get it working, and it's consuming a lot of time. The Vetur documentation is just "tossed salad" and doesn't target specific issues; it needs a lot of editing, too. Can I get by without Vetur?

Vetur can't find tsconfig etc.
Cannot find module '../assets/ etc.

Comment: Vetur is an extension made to ease development with vue on vscode but is not a must so you can code without.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of necessity, nothing obliges you to use it it just helps with for example definition jumping and completion in some cases.

As stated in some comments, its main purpose it to ease development and if doesn't do that for you no need to have it. I would still recommend setting some time aside so you can figure it out and try and having it running :D